# .not() function jquery hides other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two tabulation in the same page which consist of different contents. So the tabulation active state hides other tabs and that's ok but it also hides the second tabulation texts. It should show both texts of active state or the text content should show for both.
Here's my code

```js
$(function() {
  var tabsArray = [];
  $(".tabdiv").each(function(index) {
    var elementID = $(this).attr("id"); //get UID of each tabdiv
    tabsArray.push("#" + elementID);
  });

  /*var first = document.querySelector('.tabdiv');*/
  //show only the first tabdiv in the tabulation
  $(tabsArray).each(function(index, element) {
    if (index === 0) {
      //get first elem of the array tabsArray
      $(element).show();
    } else {
      $(element).hide();
    }
  });
  $(".tablink").click(function() {
    var tab = '#' + $(this).data("tab");
    $(".tabdiv").not(tab).hide();
    $(tab).show();
  });
  //adds a class of active when the tab is clicked
  $('.mergers ').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("mergers")) {
      $('.mergers').removeClass('activeCol activeTxt');
      $(this).addClass("activeCol activeTxt");
      $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0) !important');
    }
  });

  


}); //end ready
```

```css
.showFirst {
  display: block;
}

.activeCol {
  background-color: #ff8a8a;
}

.main-tab-flex {
  height: auto!important;
}

.mergers h3 {
  display: flex;
}

a.tablink {
  width: 100%;
}

.tabdiv h4,
.content {
  text-align: left;
}

.content {
  /*padding-top: 10px;*/
}

.tabdiv {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabdiv h4 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mergers h3 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.mergers {
  margin: 1px;
}

.ftabContent {
  width: 100%;
}

.fTabContainer {
  padding: 5px;
}

.fTabContainer,
.ftabContent,
.main-tab-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.main-tab-flex {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tab-title {
  width: 80%!important;
  height: auto!important;
  margin-bottom: 1px!important;
  padding: 5px!important;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tab-title {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 0 3px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.tab-title span {
  color: #88481D;
  padding: 0 15px 10px 11px;
  text-align: center!important;
}

.tab-title:last-child span {
  border-right: none;
}

span.tablink {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255, 157, 39);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.item-tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  order: 1;
}

.middle {
  order: 2;
}

.bottom {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Tabulation 1
<div class="main-tab-flex">
  <div class="fTabContainer">
    <div class="mergers">
      <h3><a class="tablink" data-tab="t1">Tab 1</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="mergers">
      <h3><a class="tablink" data-tab="t2">Tab 2</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="mergers">
      <h3><a class="tablink" data-tab="t3">Tab 3</a></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ftabContent">
    <div class="tabdiv" id="t1">
      <div class="content">Tab Content 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabdiv" id="t2">
      <div class="content">Tab Content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabdiv" id="t3">
      <div class="content">Tab Content 3</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div style="background-color:#333;border:4px solid black;"></div>
Tabulation 2


<div class="main-tab-flex">
  <div class="fTabContainer">
    <div class="mergers">
      <h3><a class="tablink" data-tab="t4">Tab 11</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="mergers">
      <h3><a class="tablink" data-tab="t5">Tab 22</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="mergers">
      <h3><a class="tablink" data-tab="t6">Tab 23</a></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ftabContent">
    <div class="tabdiv" id="t4">
      <div class="content">Tab Content 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabdiv" id="t5">
      <div class="content">Tab Content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabdiv" id="t6">
      <div class="content">Tab Content 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try remove .not() from $(".tabdiv").not(tab).hide(); It is necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to limit the behavior to the currently clicked group, you need to target the parent first, using [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

In your example:

```
...
$(this).closest('.main-tab-flex').find(".tabdiv").not(tab).hide();
...
```

```js
$(function() {
  var tabsArray = [];
  $(".tabdiv").each(function(index) {
    var elementID = $(this).attr("id"); //get UID of each tabdiv
    tabsArray.push("#" + elementID);
  });

  /*var first = document.querySelector('.tabdiv');*/
  //show only the first tabdiv in the tabulation
  $(tabsArray).each(function(index, element) {
    if (index === 0) {
      //get first elem of the array tabsArray
      $(element).show();
    } else {
      $(element).hide();
    }
  });
  $(".tablink").click(function() {
    var tab = '#' + $(this).data("tab");
    $(this).closest('.main-tab-flex').find(".tabdiv").not(tab).hide();
    $(tab).show();
  });
  //adds a class of active when the tab is clicked
  $('.mergers ').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("mergers")) {
      $('.mergers').removeClass('activeCol activeTxt');
      $(this).addClass("activeCol activeTxt");
      $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0) !important');
    }
  });

  


}); //end ready
```

```css
.showFirst {
  display: block;
}

.activeCol {
  background-color: #ff8a8a;
}

.main-tab-flex {
  height: auto!important;
}

.mergers h3 {
  display: flex;
}

a.tablink {
  width: 100%;
}

.tabdiv h4,
.content {
  text-align: left;
}

.content {
  /*padding-top: 10px;*/
}

.tabdiv {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabdiv h4 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mergers h3 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.mergers {
  margin: 1px;
}

.ftabContent {
  width: 100%;
}

.fTabContainer {
  padding: 5px;
}

.fTabContainer,
.ftabContent,
.main-tab-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.main-tab-flex {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tab-title {
  width: 80%!important;
  height: auto!important;
  margin-bottom: 1px!important;
  padding: 5px!important;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tab-title {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 0 3px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.tab-title span {
  color: #88481D;
  padding: 0 15px 10px 11px;
  text-align: center!important;
}

.tab-title:last-child span {
  border-right: none;
}

span.tablink {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255, 157, 39);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.item-tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  order: 1;
}

.middle {
  order: 2;
}

.bottom {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Tabulation 1
<div class="main-tab-flex">
  <div class="fTabContainer">
    <div class="mergers">
      <h3><a class="tablink" data-tab="t1">Tab 1</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="mergers">
      <h3><a class="tablink" data-tab="t2">Tab 2</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="mergers">
      <h3><a class="tablink" data-tab="t3">Tab 3</a></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ftabContent">
    <div class="tabdiv" id="t1">
      <div class="content">Tab Content 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabdiv" id="t2">
      <div class="content">Tab Content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabdiv" id="t3">
      <div class="content">Tab Content 3</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div style="background-color:#333;border:4px solid black;"></div>
Tabulation 2


<div class="main-tab-flex">
  <div class="fTabContainer">
    <div class="mergers">
      <h3><a class="tablink" data-tab="t4">Tab 11</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="mergers">
      <h3><a class="tablink" data-tab="t5">Tab 22</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="mergers">
      <h3><a class="tablink" data-tab="t6">Tab 23</a></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ftabContent">
    <div class="tabdiv" id="t4">
      <div class="content">Tab Content 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabdiv" id="t5">
      <div class="content">Tab Content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabdiv" id="t6">
      <div class="content">Tab Content 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh! Works like a charm! Thanks!